# Can Customer Community Plus users be added to account teams?

Tags: account-teams, customer-community-plus

When I try to add a user to an account team, only users with full Salesforce licenses show. Are users with Customer Community Plus licenses allowed to be added to account teams? If so, what could be preventing adding them to an account team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the below linked `Idea`, it seems Account Teams are not available for Community Users.

> ## [Default Account Teams for Partner Community Users](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0rhAAA)
>
> We just got confirmation from Salesforce Priemer Support that Partner Community users can't create Default Account Teams. Manual Account, Opportunity, and Case sharing is possible, but not Default Teams. This is is an issue due to to the nature of what Comnmunity is supposed to be. Community should be about sharing, and one of the best sharing feature of Salesforce is Default Teams. In addition to that, it creates an enormous burden for enterprises with many accounts, opportunties or cases to have to manually share each one of them. An example use case for this is contraced sales people. We have clients whose outside salesforce aren't employees and use Community for their worflow. There is ever olny one outside sales person for a particular area who wors with  specific Regional Manager. It would be ideal for that outside sales rep to add the Regionl Sales Manager to a Default Account group.

Comment: Is it still true that community users can't be added to account teams? Any workaround?